# How to delete the Shopping widget from Windows 11

Tags: windows-11, widgets

In Windows 11 Enterprise, I have enabled the 'widget' menu, added some widgets to it, and removed others.

There is only the Shopping widget ('Winkelen' in the screenshot below) that I can hide by clicking **…** and then *Hide this widget*, but when I come back later, it is visible again.

How can I permanently hide or remove the Shopping widget?

[image: Widget menu]

Update, one day later: I just found out that I can reorder the other widgets so they are *above* shopping (but only after pinning them first), so at least it is out of view now.

Comment: Do you wish to disable only one widget or all of them?

Comment: No, just the shopping widget must go

Comment: AFAIK, the specific widget can be hidden, or resized smaller (perhaps to 1 pixel?) but not removed separately: https://www.pdq.com/blog/how-to-remove-widgets-in-windows-11/

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I haven't found a way to resize a widget, are you sure that's possible? There is an option to hide it, but *that's not permanent*, as I mentioned in my question

Comment: The URL states "You can also tailor the size and settings of widgets by clicking on the ellipses (...) button on any widget."

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Well, then that site isn't (entirely) correct. The options Small, Medium and Large are not there for the shopping widget. Have you tried it yourself?

Comment: @Berend, sorry, I've stayed with Win 10  (until EOL, at which point this PC will be Linux-only).

Answer (score 0):

To completely remove and disable one Windows 11 widget, you need to
uninstall it. The tool to use is PowerShell, run as Administrator.

To remove it from your account, use this command:

```
Get-AppxPackage | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*Shopping*"} | Remove-AppxPackage
```

To remove for all users :

```
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*Shopping*"} | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Note that the `*Shopping*` search is only a guess - I don't know
its real name. You may test it by running this partial command:

```
Get-AppxPackage | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*Shopping*"}
```

Source :
[How to Disable Widgets in Windows 11 Completely](https://lazyadmin.nl/win-11/disable-widgets-windows-11/).

Comment: I'll try in the morning. Can I also get a list of all installed widgets so that I can search the exact name first?

Comment: Use something like `Get-AppxPackage > \path\file.txt`.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I don't see any obvious shopping related names in the list. There are two having *Store* in the name, but I believe those are different things: Microsoft.StorePurchaseApp for facilitating in-app purchases and Microsoft.Services.Store.Engagement for getting in-app user feedback. This shopping app seems to be just for showing ads that open https://www.bing.com/shop when clicked.

Comment: Strange. Perhaps the word "Shopping" is badly translated. If you can publish the list online (example pastebin) and give us the url, we could have a look.